# How to skip checkout step & shipping address magento 2

Tags: magento2

I  want that customer  that belong to group 1 pass his order without filling the information of shipping address so how to proceed please

Comment: You can use the virtual, downloadable or gift card product to checkout without populate shipping information.

Comment: but my product should be configurable

Comment: Yes, you can use configurable products with child products are virtual. If the product weight is 0, Magento 2 will auto create virtual products

Comment: i tried this but still display trhe shipping  addresse and the possibility to add new address ( i use the one page checkout )